# ActiveDirectory works locally but not on the server, WHY?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, localhost

When I call a the GetAuthorizationGroups of a user, locally it works. But on the server I get this error message: `While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred.`

Can someone tell me what I have to do so that it will work everywhere?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be issue with permissions under which the said code is running - this user must have permission to access the AD. So try impersonating your ASP.NET app under domain user. For trouble-shooting, you may build a console app with similar code and try to run it under domain user (you may have to disable UAC).

Comment: the part of impersonate is in the file web.config, not?

Comment: @Tassisto, you need to modify web.config file to enable impersonation and provide identity(user name/pwd) to impersonate with.

Comment: in the impersonate part I can give the username & password, right?

Comment: @Tassisto, that's correct - use some domain user account (it will likely to have AD access)

Comment: where do i have to use domain user, in the script of AD or in impersonate?

Comment: Well - I believe at both places: while impersonating, you need a user that has access to AD (he/she should be member of Authorization Access Group). The second user will be domain user because then only you will get his groups from AD. OTOH, see if these links helps: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474038/userprincipal-getauthorizationgroups-throws-exceptions and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474038/userprincipal-getauthorizationgroups-throws-exceptions